# Trying to make a working upload button to upload video files to a local video folder

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make this function in python and I keep getting this error.

> RuntimeError: Model class registration.models.RegistrationProfile doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What function? Please show the code

Comment: I am trying to make it so when I hit the upload button and then save it saves to a local folder called "Videos"

Comment: from django.db import models

class Video(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, verbose_name="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ": " + str(self.videofile)

Comment: TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',)
           
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL= "/media/